# how to solve Apache Error i already changes the ports but couldn't what the Error is?

Tags: apache

```
03:32:35[Apache]Problem detected! 
03:32:35[Apache]Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
03:32:35[Apache]Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free! 
03:32:35[Apache]You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application 
03:32:35[Apache]or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port 
03:32:35[Apache]Attempting to start Apache app... 
03:32:35[Apache]Status change detected: running
```

Answer (score 0):

As log said, Port 80 is already used by another process
to check wich process use port : 
**WINDOWS**: `netstat -a -b` 
**LINUX**  : `sudo netstat -tulpn` (must run with root)

To change the port of Apache, you have to modify this file: 
**APACHE_INSTALLATION_PATH/conf/httpd.conf** and change this configuration `Listen 80` to the port you want to use, example : `Listen 8085`
**N.B:** in your browser you must type this url `http://www.mywebsite.com:8085` instead of `http://www.mywebsite.com` ( == `http://www.mywebsite.com:80`)
You must restart your apache server 
I think that skype is using port 80, but i'm not sure